# Groovy Spock. How to verify interaction with two arguments method?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

Trying to use Spock mocks to verify method invocation arguments.
[Documentation](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_mocking) and most of the examples in the internet contain example for single argument.

How to implement capture and verification of multiple arguments in a mock method call?

```
interface MyAction{
  String doSomething(int first, String second);
}

// spec
def "should do something"(){
  given:
  MyAction action = Mock()

  when:
  action.doSomething(123, "abc")

  then:

  // how to verify that (first == 123) and (second == "abc") ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just list them like you'd do for a single argument.

```
import spock.lang.*

class ASpec extends Specification {
    // spec
    def "should do something"(){
        given:
            MyAction action = Mock()

        when:
            action.doSomething(123, "abc")

        then:
        1 * action.doSomething(123, "abc")    
    }
}

interface MyAction{
  String doSomething(int first, String second);
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJyFjz0OgzAMRvecwmICVIFot1YdOAATJ0gdA1EhQST9U8Xdm4BAtEu9JFbe--zIrteDBdNrvCYtV3USM4YtNwbysicEelpSwoBvZCWRW6kVvBm4SlMnEk53QRUEptG3VoDQYHRHtpGqDsJohn3V8k7quLa-ileOUySfjzMUbpUwYiv1aH6dGU2ELpcpYbY_7CDgFww2pv0yM4j_mJ6a8JGNjEllaag40rqj_0hpB2fBNsGBUMnB2N3yagi1EtHJx3wADGJmCw)

---

Edit: an example mismatch will show which argument didn't match and why.

```
Too few invocations for:
            
               1 * action.doSomething(123, "abc")   (0 invocations)
            
               Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
            
               1 * action.doSomething(123, 'bc')
               One or more arguments(s) didn't match:
               0: <matches>
               1: argument == expected
                  |        |  |
                  bc       |  abc
                           false
                           1 difference (66% similarity)
                           (-)bc
                           (a)bc
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept this answer. Unfortunately I did not express correctly the intention. In the given answer we can't make fine grained assertions on what exactly failed: we see only amount of invocations with "these exact values". Could you add a more complex case with the arguments being captured and assertions that visually show the difference between expected and actual arguments?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, Spock will render why it didn't match.